# why does the begin method take out parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm new to asynchronous programming, amd I was reading a book that shows some example APIs below:

```
// synchronous version
SearchResults GetResults(int page, int pageSize, out int itemsReturned);  

// asynchronous version
IAsyncResult BeginGetResults(int page,
                             int pageSize,
                             out int itemsReturned,
                             AsyncCallback callback,
                             object state);
SearchResults EndGetResults(out int itemsReturned, IAsyncResult iar);
```

note that the Begin method takes an "out" parameter as `out int itemsReturned`

Below is the author's explanation:

**It turns out this is the abstraction leaking. The CLR has no notion of out parameters; it is a C# language idiom. At the CLR level, out parameters are simply ref parameters, and it is the C# compiler that
enforces a specific usage pattern. Because asynchronous programming model is not a language-specific feature, it must conform to the needs of the CLR. Now ref parameters can be both inputs and outputs; therefore, the CLR does not know that these out parameters are only used for output and so they must be placed on the Begin method as well as the End method.**

I'm still confused, below is my question:

Q1- We know that `out` parameter needs to be assigned a value before the method returns, so in this case, is `itemsReturned` set to 0 after Begin method finishes? what's the point to set sth you know that it is not correct at the current stage?

Q2-Isn't that more straightforward to get rid of `out int itemsReturned` in the Begin method as:

```
IAsyncResult BeginGetResults(int page,
                             int pageSize,                            
                             AsyncCallback callback,
                             object state);
```

and we can still use `out int itemsReturned`in the End method?

Comment: note: if you're just starting looking at async, frankly I advise **against** looking at `IAsyncResult` - that is the **ancient, obsolete** async pattern; the preferred idiom these days is `async` i.e. `[Value]Task[<T>]`

Comment: @MarcGravell  yes, I just need to study basic first, to have building block. will learn Task soon

Comment: no, this isn't a question of "basic first"; there's nothing "basic" about `IAsyncResult` - it is **incredibly** complex and subtle, and frankly there is almost zero intersection between the two approaches; learning `IAsyncResult` **will not help you** learn about `Task`; if anything it will just add confusion to an already confusing topic; in my opinion: **unless you absolutely need to** (because you're working on an ancient system that can't be updated), do not look at `IAsyncResult` **at all**

Comment: to add to that; the old `IAsyncResult` is complex *precisely because* the language and runtime features that underpin task-based async didn't exist; the entire point of the modern async is to **make this topic approachable**; and once again: `IAsyncResult` is not a "building block" for modern async, in the same way that learning how to ride, groom and feed a horse is not a building block for driving a car; those were necessary skills for frequent travellers **before cars existed**

Answer (score 3):

Q1. I agree; this seems like a terrible design idea by the author, and is not typical by any means; I suspect the author didn't have a great grasp of the *admittedly confusing* pattern, and simply hacked something in; perhaps they already had the `out` API on the non-async method, and wanted it to be consistent?

Q2. Yes, but I'd go one further and put the items returned as an additional **property** on `SearchResults`, not as an `out` parameter on `EndGetResults`

But emphasis: this is **not the current/preferred way of doing async code**; if you're starting out, *don't go this route*; I'd just have:

```cs
SearchResults Search(int page, int pageSize);
async ValueTask<SearchResults> SearchAsync(int page, int pageSize);
```

and have `public int ItemsReturned {get;}` on `SearchResults`.